# Use Case of Static Agents in AEM

Tags: aem

In Agents on author, I have a static replication agent.

So what is the benefit of using static replication agent in AEM?

Answer (score 4):

The OOTB static agent (if configured properly) will produce static representations of nodes on the file-system upon modifications. There are only a few use cases for this:

1. A static representation of repository on the file system (as the name says). This can be used for non-dispatcher modelled proxy servers.
2. Backup and versioning outside the repository. For example, if financial services regulations require static snapshots of each modification on the system for archiving purposes.
3. Quick extraction of media from repository for larger asset based projects where media (images) can be consumed by non-AEM systems directly from the disk-storage. Good example would be ffmpeg manipulation of videos etc.

All of the above won't be useful in modern architecture/practices as there are better ways of meeting these data extraction and archiving requirements.

As [Adobe documentation](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-2/deploy/configuring/replication.html) says:

> This is an "Agent that stores a static representation of a node into the filesystem.".
>   For example with the default settings, content pages and dam assets are stored under /tmp, either as HTML or the appropriate asset format. See the Settings and Rules tabs for the configuration.
>   This was requested so that when the page is requested directly from the application server the content can be seen. **This is a specialized agent and (probably) will not be required for most instances.**